# Foreign key not stored in database using embed form in symfony 3

Tags: database, forms, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I have the following entities, form types and controller

Entity Client

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ClientRepository")
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contacts", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $contacts;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->contacts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add contact
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Contacts $contact
     *
     * @return Client
     */
    public function addContact(\AppBundle\Entity\Contacts $contact)
    {
        $this->contacts[] = $contact;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove contact
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Contacts $contact
     */
    public function removeContact(\AppBundle\Entity\Contacts $contact)
    {
        $this->contacts->removeElement($contact);
    }

    /**
     * Get contacts
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getContacts()
    {
        return $this->contacts;
    }
}
```

Contacts entity is as below

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Contacts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contacts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ContactsRepository")
 */
class Contacts
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fullname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fullname;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_type", type="smallint")
     */
    private $userType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="contacts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $client;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fullname
     *
     * @param string $fullname
     *
     * @return Contacts
     */
    public function setFullname($fullname)
    {
        $this->fullname = $fullname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fullname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullname()
    {
        return $this->fullname;
    }

    /**
     * Set userType
     *
     * @param integer $userType
     *
     * @return Contacts
     */
    public function setUserType($userType)
    {
        $this->userType = $userType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userType
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getUserType()
    {
        return $this->userType;
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Client $client
     *
     * @return Contacts
     */
    public function setClient(\AppBundle\Entity\Client $client = null)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Client
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }
}
```

Client form type is as below

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Client;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;


class ClientForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Client Name')))
            ->add('address', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Address')))
            ->add('contacts', CollectionType::class, array(
                    // each entry in the array will be an "email" field
                    'entry_type'   => ContactsForm::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Client::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Contacts form type is as below

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Contacts;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class ContactsForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fullname', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Full Name')))
                ->add('user_type', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Co-Owner'))
                );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Contacts::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Finally the controller to store data in two different tables being client as main table and contacts having foreign ken as client_id from table client is as below

/

```
**
     * @Route("/client/add", name="add_client")
     */
    public function addClientAction(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $form = $this->createForm(ClientForm::class, $client);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $client = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($client);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'notice',
                'Client Added!'
            );
            return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
        }
        return $this->render('default/addClient.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));


    }
```

The problem here is the data is added in both tables but the foreign key of the added client is not stored in table contacts, the value is null

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537923/persistence-with-embedded-forms?answertab=active#tab-top) seems to work for some people may be for older version of symfony

But not luck to me. How to insert the foreign id as well. Am new to symfony and I am using symfony 3.2

Comment: I created another entity lets say projects and everything having same as in the contacts entity, this worked for me

public function addProject(\AppBundle\Entity\Projects $project)
    {
        $this->projects[] = $project;
        $project->setClient($this);
        return $this;
    }

This code stores the client key on projects table however I am still not sure what is the issue with contacts entity. I deleted everything related to contacts, cleared the cache and created the new one, did everything as done for projects but client id is not stored in contacts table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems for me like a little mess up.
I guess you should add a contact from ContactController addAction.

Than in your Contact form type add EntityType, so you can choose a client for your contact. Here is some examples: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Or you can set client manually by simple $contact->setClient($client) before you presist.

PS: rename Contacts entity to Contact. It is a little confusing)